# Use of unresolved identifier 'response' (after """dataTask.resume()""")

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I think I need to write my class elsewhere but I don't know where.
The error shows on the line after `dataTask.resume()` at the end.

```
let postData = NSMutableData(data: "email=hello@test.com".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
postData.append("&password=12345".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
postData.append("&loginbutton=Connecter".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://zzzway.com/appMango/login.php")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse)
  }
})
 dataTask.resume()

    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    if httpResponse.contains("chute")
    {
    print("exists")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
if httpResponse.contains("chute") {
     print("exists")
}
```

should be inside `completionHandler`

---

To accomplish what you need do

```
if let str = response?.url?.absoluteString , str.contains("chute") {

}
```

Comment: But then the .contains doesn't work anymore... I get "Value of type 'HTTPURLResponse?' has no member 'contains'"

Comment: why u need to check `response ` ? don't you need to process `data` ?

Comment: I need to check if the response from the HTTPURLResponse contains the word "chute"